# Compiler cannot convert the arguments passed to swprintf function, winapi

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

can you help me with this code? I cannot fix it. There is problem with swprintf function.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
        LPTSTR strPrincipal = new TCHAR[20],
               strInterest = new TCHAR[20], strPeriods = new TCHAR[20],
               strInterestEarned = new TCHAR[20], strAmountEarned = new TCHAR[20];

    double Principal, AnnualRate, InterestEarned;
        double FutureValue, RatePerPeriod;
        int    NumberOfPeriods, CompoundType;
        double i;
        int n;

    swprintf(strInterestEarned, "$%.2f", InterestEarned);
    swprintf(strAmountEarned,   "$%.2f", FutureValue);
   }
```

Here are errors:

```
Error   1   error C2665: 'swprintf' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
Error   2   error C2665: 'swprintf' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Comment: You should stop using TCHAR unless you need to compile for win 98

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You must be sick of saying that by now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got your parameters wrong / in the wrong order. Have you checked the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Method signature:

```
int swprintf(
   wchar_t *buffer,
   size_t count,
   const wchar_t *format [,
   argument]...
);
```

That page gives the following example for `swprintf`:

```
// crt_swprintf.c
// wide character example
// also demonstrates swprintf returning error code
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   wchar_t buf[100];
   int len = swprintf( buf, 100, L"%s", L"Hello world" );
   printf( "wrote %d characters\n", len );
   len = swprintf( buf, 100, L"%s", L"Hello\xffff world" );
   // swprintf fails because string contains WEOF (\xffff)
   printf( "wrote %d characters\n", len );
}
```

I think you'd want something along the lines of:

```
swprintf( strInterestEarned, 20, L"%.2f", InterestEarned );
```

Comment: A less error-prone solution would take advantage of the function template, that automatically deduces the target buffer size: `wchar_t strInterestEarned[20]; swprintf( strInterestEarned, L"$%.2f", InterestEarned );`.

Comment: @IInspectable that's what the OP had tried initially but hadn't explicitly used `wchar_t` or indicated that the string literal was `wchar_t` with the `L` prefix... I wasn't aware of the function template so pointed OP toward adding the `count` argument. I agree, having the compiler automatically deduce the target buffer size is better ;)

Comment: Not quite on spot: The real issue is, that the OP dynamically allocated the arrays, and received a pointer to the first element (due to array-to-pointer conversion). You cannot use the function template with pointer types; they require array types to be passed as the first argument.

Comment: @IInspectable: Actually I think the real issue is that the OP is passing an Ansi string to a Unicode function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Both of which are errors, and need to be fixed. However, since the OP picked the function template with an implied size template parameter, the proposed solution goes off into the wrong direction. Passing a Unicode character string literal and an array with automatic storage duration is the real solution. One could also argue, that using a floating point data type to represent currency values is inappropriate as well.

Comment: @IInspectable as above, I agree there's a better solution. Do you want to add another answer? Or I could update mine?

Comment: One answer is enough. You can update it to include the additional information.